# Kafka LogAppendTime unit?

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka’s documentation does not state what unit is used for the record timestamps when LogAppendTime is turned on.

Is it milliseconds or microseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> documentation does not state

[Yes, it does](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#protocol_messages) - `log_append_time_ms`

You can also use DumpLogSegments class to verify record content

Comment: Thanks. It’s pretty we’ll hidden if it’s only documented in the low-level protocol description and not in the docs for producer or consumer settings.

Comment: It's not a client config. It's part of the record storage protocol